# How to adjust the thickness of a stroke in Sketch?

Tags: stroke, sketch-app, borders

I have an icon and I would like to make it thinner but it has a fill instead of a border. As far as I know, it's not possible to change the thickness of the fill, so I need to find a way to convert the fill to a border. I think scaling won't help much.

[image: test1234]

If I uncheck the fill and check the border checkbox, this is the result.

[image]

How to adjust the thickness of this icon in Sketch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Sketch can't do all the work for you

There's no way to make a compound shape into a single line drawing. That's true of every vector app I've used.

## All is not lost

You have a simple vector object. Just cut it up and reassemble the lines to create the line graphic you're after. In this case, you just need the surrounding frame and the middle line. Those are easy to isolate once you break the shape apart.

Here's a quick illustration of the process using the mailbox icon from FontAwesome.

[image]

After I converted the font to outlines, I had essentially the same starting point: a solid shape.

1. Split it's paths: <kbd>Layer</kbd> > <kbd>Paths</kbd> > <kbd>Split</kbd>
2. Dump the fills and add borders.
3. Trim down the internal shape (the front panel of the box) to an open line using the <kbd>Scissors</kbd> tool.
4. Move everything into place and adjust the internal line's outer vectors to overlap the surrounding shape.

Comment: @CeceXX I added a bit of explanation. I needed practice with it myself (^‿- )

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation! It is much appreciated.